# Which platform for mobile development?

Tags: qt, java-me, symbian

I have to develop an application which requires  Bluetooth and profile change functionality for Symbian phones. After spending sometime I found that following options:

1. Java: but java does not allow to change profile
2. Symbian C++: I read basics for Symbian C++ and created some basic stuffs. Symbian extended APIs provide simple APIs for Profile and Bluetooth (I haven't tested yet). But its required lot of efforts to grab these. Specially certificate singing problem. I want to test my application on different devices and wish to give my friends whom having different cellphones. But couldn't due to signing problem.
3. QT: I am still confused on this. Whether this platform capable to fulfill my requirement or not. Secondly which phone supports QT or not...

Honestly, I am bit frustrated while writing this. I am looking someone, experience in these matter, to guide me in this situation.

Comment: Add Python to your list. It might help if you provided more detail (ie. are you dealing with just S40 or S60).

Comment: Python is good but as I have been working with c-style languages, so don't want to add further learning curve. Secondly, it also has limitations. Anyhow, its a good option as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine native C++ with Qt. Though you'll lose some of the cross-platform nature of Qt by mixing native C++ with it.

See the [XQProfile](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Changing_profile_programmatically_in_Qt) example on Forum Nokia Wiki for mixing Qt and native Symbian C++ for profile changing.

Qt can be installed to practically all devices from S60 3rd Edition FP1 (S60 3.1) onwards. Newer device models ship with Qt preinstalled. Forum Nokia has device specifications that you can [filter based on Qt availability](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/?filter=qt).

Answer (score 1):

QT (+ QML) is the language of choice going forward. I believe it is currently on the following phones: N8,C7,C6,E7. i version 4.6.1 with version 4.7 which has the QML support due shortly.

However if you need to target current and older devices then your only choice is Symbian C++.